# devextreme datagrid looks very faint when disabled

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datagrid, devextreme

I disable my devextreme datagrid in various situations, but when it is disabled, it appears so small that it cannot be read. How can I solve this problem?

```
<div className={this.state.disabledGrid || this.disabled() ? '.dx-datagrid.dx-state-disabled' : ''}>
    <Grid blablablabla />
</div>
```

CSS file :

```
/* DataGrid etkisizleştirildiğinde daha belirgin veri görünümü */
.dx-datagrid-disabled {
    background-color: #f2f2f2 !important;
    /* Etkisizleştirildiğinde arka plan rengi */
    /* Diğer özelleştirmeler */
}

.dx-datagrid-disabled .dx-datagrid-content .dx-row {
    color: #000 !important;
    /* Veri satırı metin rengi - daha belirgin bir siyah */
    background-color: #fff !important;
    /* Veri satırı arka plan rengi - daha belirgin bir beyaz */
    /* Diğer özelleştirmeler */
}

.dx-datagrid-disabled .dx-datagrid-content .dx-row.dx-row-lines {
    border-color: #ddd !important;
    /* Satır aralıklarının rengi */
}

.dx-datagrid-disabled .dx-datagrid-content .dx-row.dx-row-lines.dx-row-focused {
    border-color: #000 !important;
    /* Odaklanılmış satır aralıklarının rengi - daha belirgin bir siyah */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think u should try it  :

Can u use ***OnCellPrepared*** in your ***DataGrid*** to change color in data Columns. And use it to highlight your data, ex:

```
e.cellElement.css("color", "green");
```

u can read more OnCellPrepared